# Block that can access self and be used throughout an instance

Tags: objective-c, objective-c-blocks

I want a block that is available throughout a class, so it can be re-used many times by different methods in the instance.

I want that block to be able to reference self.

I want to not have the block create any nasty retain cycles by retaining self.

So far I am stumped.  I managed to create block in the .m outside of any method definitions, and that got me partway - I could reuse the block everywhere, but I couldn't access self.  I tried putting the block into an ivar but I'm doing something wrong there and now I'm getting random EXC_BAD_ACCESS.  Can someone explain it simply, line by line?

Comment: Can you show some code of what you've done so far?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out.

In MyClass.h:

```
typedef void (^DefaultFailureBlock)();

@property (copy) DefaultFailureBlock defaultFailureBlock;
```

in the init method:

```
__block MyClass *selfReq = self;
self.defaultFailureBlock = ^{
    //use selfReq instead of self in here.
};
```

Interestingly, if you accidentally refer to self inside the block, you will have a retain cycle, and Analyze will not complain.  I put an NSLog in dealloc to prove that it is actually being dealloced, and it is.

Oh and don't forget to [defaultFailureBlock release]; in dealloc too...

Comment: Use a __weak reference to self to avoid a retain cycle inside your block, see 'Blocks" section of these ARC best-practices: http://amattn.com/2011/12/07/arc_best_practices.html

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
typedef void (^MyBlock)();

@implementation MyClass
{
    MyBlock block;
}

- (id) init
{
   self = [super init];
   if (!self)
      return nil;

   __block MyClass* _self = self;

   block = [^ {
       [_self sendSomeMsg];
   } copy];
}
```

Note the `__block` storage type. Quoting [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/cocoa/Conceptual/Blocks/Articles/bxVariables.html): "At function level are __block variables. These are mutable within the block (and the enclosing scope) and are preserved if any referencing block is copied to the heap."

Comment: This is close to what I ended up with.  I use a @property with (copy)  purely because I think it reads better compared to [^{[];} copy];

Answer (score 1):

This idiom may help you to remove the exc_bad_access (ARC code).

```
// get a weak reference to self
__weak id weakSelf = self;
block = ^()
{
    // now the block is executing so we get a strong reference to self
    // (this prevents self from disappearing until the block is done executing)
    id strongSelf = weakSelf;
    if (strongSelf != nil)
    {
        // do whatever work you intended for this block
    }
};
```

Comment: Seems like you'd want to use __block instead of __weak.  Maybe they mean the same thing but __block makes the intention explicit.

Comment: In ARC code __block has different semantics. It doesn't prevent a retain and should only be used if you intend to change the value of the variable.